# HTML photo slideshow with dynamic uploaded photos

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, slideshow

I'm looking for a photo slideshow to use in a web page (HTML, php and JS/jQuery). It should support fullscreen and animations as well as a large number of images. The slideshow should display all the images in a specific folder. By now, I'm using Superslides (http://archive.nicinabox.com/superslides), which works pretty good.

But here is my question. The slideshow will be projected during an event and I've already developed a PHP script for photo upload that puts images in the specified folder. The slideshow (possibly a modified version of Superslides or a new project from scratch) should first display all the new images then, after the first time all the new images have been shown, it should check if newer images have been uploaded. If so, it should display them. Else it should start a cycle with the old images. It shouldn't display all the old images before check if newer images have been added! It could check for newer images in a scheduled manner, or it could receive a "push notification" (I don't know if this is possible with JS, maybe with AJAX?).

Is there anything out-of-the-box or a tutorial to follow? Keep in mind that I'm not an expert with internet technology (I do desktop development for work), I'm quite skilled with PHP, but not with JS...

UPDATE: This is what I'm doing so far... This way it doesn't work! The Superslides is not initialized correctly (it doesn't count the right number of images, I suppose). Moreover, there's not a "priority" queue with newest photos first. Finally, the list of images is not updated programmatically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST PHOTO PLAYER</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/superslides.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slides">
      <div class="slides-container" id="slides-foto-test">
      </div>

      <nav class="slides-navigation">
        <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
        <a href="#" class="prev">Previous</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "photo-list.php",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(i,filename) {
              $("#slides-foto-test").append("<img src='" + filename + "'>");
            });
          }
        }); 
      });
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.superslides.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#slides').superslides({
          hashchange: true,
          play: 4000
        });

        $('#slides').on('mouseenter', function() {
          $(this).superslides('stop');
          console.log('Stopped')
        });
        $('#slides').on('mouseleave', function() {
          $(this).superslides('start');
          console.log('Started')
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the **photo-list.php** file:

```
<?php
  $filenameArray = array();
  $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/images/a-folder/');
  while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
      array_push($filenameArray, "images/a-folder/$file");
    }
  }
  echo json_encode($filenameArray);
?>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place for helping with programming problems, not a discussion board.

Comment: We want code to eat bro!

Comment: you need js to take the image from the input and append it to the slider

Comment: @MadDog I don't know what you mean with "programming problem"... I surely have a problem because I don't know how to give "priority" to newer images... Asking for a software design pattern is as useful as asking for a bug resolution, in my point of view. Maybe I've got difficulties to explain what I want to achieve, because of my bad english...

Comment: @madalinivascu, thank you. This is what I'm doing now. But the old images and the new ones are "merged" in the same queue, so the new images are not shown prior to the old ones... I must wait for the cycle to complete before see the new images...

Comment: If your current slider stores images in an array, you can insert new elements in the position you want with splice method https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Might I suggest you edit your question to include the code you are using so we can better assist with an answer?

Comment: Ok @ChrisSpittles! Thank you! I've updated my question! But please keep in mind that I can completely change my approach. What I've tried so far is just a test, is not mandatory to use Superslides!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a "race condition".

Your code at the top (`$( document ).ready()`) says "When the DOM is loaded, make server query. When server query responds, populate the HTML images."

Your code at the bottom says "When the DOM is loaded, start the slideshow with given images".

While the slideshow code should fire immediately after the AJAX request fires, it will be operating **before** the AJAX responds (except in some extreme cases).

Therefore you are starting the slideshow on an unpopulated image array.

---

Two solutions:

1 After the AJAX response, populate the HTML and start the slideshow at that point

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.superslides.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "photo-list.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,filename) {
          $("#slides-foto-test").append("<img src='" + filename + "'>");
        });

        // Now trigger the slideshow script
        $('#slides').superslides({
          hashchange: true,
          play: 4000
        });
        $('#slides').on('mouseenter', function() {
          $(this).superslides('stop');
          console.log('Stopped')
        });
        $('#slides').on('mouseleave', function() {
          $(this).superslides('start');
          console.log('Started')
        });

      }
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

2 Why not generate the HTML in PHP, and populate the image array at that point? Saves a server call, page loads faster for the user and you eliminate the race condition.

Comment: That's not my main problem... The problem is that I want the slideshow to autoupdate itself based on newly added images (it has to show them first).

Comment: Anyway, you deserve the bounty because you are the only one to answer!

Comment: Thanks. I quickly checked the docs and there's nothing there that allows the library to "reload" when the images change. However there is a slidshowe.update() - have a look in `superslides_test.js` for an example of how to use it. I'm guessing by the name that this may do what  you want.

Comment: Yes, @Robbie! I'm already using it! It's almost done... Thank you!